# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 1: invalid start byte

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I had built chatbot following this github: 
https://github.com/llSourcell/tensorflow_chatbot

Also I get data on: https://github.com/suriyadeepan/easy_seq2seq/tree/master/data

I use tensorflow 0.12 with python 3.5. Can someone help me fix this problem: >> Mode : test

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "execute.py", line 324, in 
    decode()
    File "execute.py", line 220, in decode
    enc_vocab, _ = data_utils.initialize_vocabulary(enc_vocab_path)
    File "D:\My_document\AI\Chatbot_Conversation\tensorflow_chatbot-master\data_utils.py", line 86, in initialize_vocabulary
    rev_vocab.extend(f.readlines())
    File "C:\Users\Hoang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 131, in readlines
    s = self.readline()
    File "C:\Users\Hoang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 124, in readline
    return compat.as_str_any(self._read_buf.ReadLineAsString())
    File "C:\Users\Hoang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\compat.py", line 106, in as_str_any
    return as_str(value)
    File "C:\Users\Hoang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\compat.py", line 84, in as_text
    return bytes_or_text.decode(encoding)
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 1: invalid start byte
```

This error mean that I need to revise my data to utf-8?
I appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: It seems there is some character which is not in ASCII range. You need to convert your text in unicode.

Comment: You mean my data ? https://stackoverflow.com/users/5281012/shivam-jindal

Comment: Yes, in the data you have some non-ascii character which you are converting into string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to read the data using encoding='unicode_escape'. For example

**df= pd.read_csv('file_name.csv',encoding ='unicode_escape')**

It worked for me.